# How best to copy a configured Log4j Appender

Tags: java, log4j

I have a scenario where I want to log to a custom Log4j Appender by a session Id.  In other words, I want to setup one logger for a package (e.g. com.foo.bar) and then append custom Appenders.  Only if a request comes in with the same session id, I want to log messages to be written for Appenders that match the session Id. When I turn on the logging, we have to dynamically add an Appender on the fly and set its name to the session Id.  What I would like to do is have a pre-configured Appender that I grab from the log4j.xml file and make a copy of it and set the name equal to the session id and then add it to my new logger.  In order to pull the appender from the configuration file, the only way I've found to be able to do that is by attaching an appender to a dummy logger (i.e. support_logger in this case)

```
<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p: %c - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="support_logger">
    <level value="debug" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
</logger>
```

By doing this, I can then get to the appender by coding:

```
Appender appender = Logger.getLogger("support_logger").getAppender("console") );
```

The issue that I'm having now is that I need to create a new logger, based on some package that I'm interested in and then take the appender above and all its configuration and add it to the new logger, but setting the name of the Appender to the Session Id.

```
Logger newLogger = Logger.getLogger("com.foo.bar");
appender.setName(req.getSession().getId()); 
newLogger.addAppender(appender)
```

This happens perfectly the first time in, but if I have another session id for the same package, then the "console" appender is no longer there.  When I set the name on the Appender, I overlay the console configuration and can't seem to get it back since the logger is already initialized.

So my question is this. I'm looking for a simple way to clone "console" appender to another appender and set the name with a session id and keep the original "console" logger configured so that I can access it on subsequent requests.

I've written an Appender clone method, but I'm not sure if there's a better way to do this with the Log4j API.

Answer (score -1):

**Cloning an object or changing referenced objects**

Yes, you don't clone the appender, you rename it with the following line:

```
appender.setName(req.getSession().getId());
```

Before you do this, you need to create a deep copy. Else, you will just rename the existing appender "console" to "id". If you need to know how to create a deep copy, [here is an efficient way](http://javatechniques.com/blog/faster-deep-copies-of-java-objects/).

After you created a deep copy of your appender, you can rename it using setName and use it as appender.

**Detail Information**

You claim, you the new logger is the issue:

> The issue that I'm having now is that I need to create a new logger,

That's not true, because creating new Loggers is sth. you do anyway for each class or each category. But usually, the existing log4j configuration will decide based on packages or names, which appender will apply. But you need a single file for each session, thus a new appender (which it's own Name *AND* file).

So what you actually need to do is like this (pseudocode):

```
Logger newLogger = Logger.getLogger("com.foo.bar");
FileAppender fa = null;
Appender appender = Logger.getLogger("support_logger").getAppender("console") );
try {
    fa = (FileAppender) fa;
} catch (...) {
    // TODO: put sth here
}
FileAppender sessionfileappender = AppenderUtils.deepcopy(fa);
sessionfileappender.setName(req.getSession().getId());
sessionfileappender.setFile("session-" + req.getSession().getId());
newLogger.addAppender(sessionfileappender)
```

So in fact, you need to code the Method `FileAppender AppenderUtils.deepcopy(FileAppender fa)`.

**Creating a new appender is easier**

In fact, it might be easier to just create a `new FileAppender(Layout layout, String filename)`, see the [constructor javadoc](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/FileAppender.html#FileAppender%28org.apache.log4j.Layout,%20java.lang.String%29). The new Pseudocode would be like this:

```
Logger newLogger = Logger.getLogger("com.foo.bar");
FileAppender fa = new FileAppender(
    Logger.getLogger("support_logger").getAppender("console").getLayout(),
    "session-" + req.getSession().getId());
newLogger.addAppender(fa);
```

Much shorter, huh? Just keep in mind, if you change the layout (which is not cloned either, just a new reference to the existing layout), you will change all layouts on the fly. So if you need a new layout, create a new one.